# Twilio End Video Capture from Local Webcam

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc, twilio

I have a functioning Twilio video-chat application that is working as I expect, other than I cannot end the video-stream when a user hits the close button. I've looked through the Javascript quick-start and have tried the following implementations: 
 (attempting to use WebRTC's method, complains that Twilio.Media.MediaStream is undefined);

```
function endVidConf(room){
    console.log('Attempting to end Vid Conf');
    room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(function(track) {
        var attachedElements = track.detach();
        attachedElements.forEach(function(element){
            element.remove();
        });
    });
    Twilio.Media.MediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
    Twilio.Media.MediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
    room.disconnect();
};
```

(using track.stop() -- the webcam is still on):

```
function endVidConf(room){
    console.log('Attempting to end Vid Conf');
    room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(function(track) {
        var attachedElements = track.detach();
        attachedElements.forEach(function(element){
            element.remove();
        });
        track.stop();
    });
    room.disconnect();
};
```

Is there something simple I'm missing or are more details about my implementation needed?

Comment: room.localParticipant.removeTracks(trackArray, true);
Where trackArray is an array of localParticipant's tracks also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make sure all code changes were within `Twilio.Connect.createLocalTracks().then(function(){...});` 
 Attempting similar fixes elsewhere did NOT work. I had to assign local tracks to trackArray, then call stop() on the entries on that array.
`Twilio.Video.createLocalTracks().then(function(localTracks) {
    ...
    trackArray = localTracks;
    trackArray[0].stop();
    trackArray[1].stop();
    ...
})`

The issue must have been with hoisting somehow.